# Prove that a graph with the same number of edges and vertices contains one cycle

Tags: graph-theory

> We have a connected graph $G(V,E)$ that has $|E|= n$ edges and $n$ vertices. 
>   Prove that the graph has one cycle in it.

I'm little bit confused here. I tried some ways but failed. Can you direct me?

Comment: Do you want to show there is at least one cycle, or exactly one?

Comment: exactly one cycle

Comment: @casteels why you deleted your answer I liked it

Comment: Thanks. The idea was right, but the way I presented it was a little bit wrong, I'm just trying to write it correctly.

Comment: I guess you are talking about the part when you tried to prove it has only one cycle right ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$G$ is connected so it has a spanning tree $T$. This uses up $n-1$ edges and has no cycles. There is one edge $e$ not used in the tree, say $e=(u,v)$. So any cycle in $G$ would have to use $e$.

Now in $T$ there is a unique path between vertices $u$ and $v$ and so in $T\cup e$ that path plus $e$ is one cycle, say $C_1$. Can there be any others? Suppose $C_2$ is another cycle, and so we know that it must use $e$ but $C_2\neq C_1$. Then $C_2\setminus e$ and $C_1\setminus e$ are two *different* paths in $T$ from $u$ to $v$, a contradiction.

Comment: why would I encounter a vertex that is on C1 ?

Comment: Since $v$ is on both cycles. So at worst you'll end up at $v$, if not before.

Comment: 100% nice solution

Comment: @WasFr There was a mistake in my solution after all (it could be that $(u,w)$ is an edge on both $C_1$ and $C_2$). One can fix this without too much trouble, but there's an easier way as above. Feel free to unaccept if you want.

Comment: after your last edit I don't see any problem in the solution 
I think it is good now .
do you agree ? if not you are invited to fix/make things more clear. 
I liked the approach and I think it is right so I'm gonna insist on choosing this answer.

waiting for your reply

Comment: @WasFr The answer in the previous edit was not quite right: Possibly it could be that the first edge $(u,w)$ used by $C_1$ in the path from $u$ to $v$ in $T$, is *also* the first edge used by $C_2$. In this case, my answer was saying that this one edge is a cycle in $T$. You can fix it by instead letting $u_0$ be the first vertex where $C_1$ and $C_2$ "split" and then letting $w$ be the first vertex after $u_0$ where they meet again. Then you get a cycle.

Answer (score 4):

Prove it by induction on the number of vertices. If it does not have a cycle, take a longest path. The last vertex must be a leaf. Remove it and apply the induction hypothesis.

Then if the graph has a cycle, remove one edge of the cycle, and apply the tree equivalence ($n$ vertices and $n-1$ edges and connected means it has no cycle).

(I had a better way before, and will update this answer if I remember it.)

Answer (score 3):

If $G$ has no cycles then it is a forest. Each tree in the forest has one edge less than vertices.

Answer (score 2):

Euler formula says $|V|-|E|+f=2$ where $f$ is the number of face.

If it has no cycle, by Euler formula the number of edges would be $|E|=n-1$. Contradiction !

If it has $2$ cycles or more, $|E|>n$. Contradiction !

Therefore $G$ has exactly one cycle.

Comment: "If it has $2$ cycles or more, then $|E|>n$" is what they want to prove.

Comment: What do you mean ? if it has 2 cycle or more, the numbers of face is at least $3$, therefore Euler formula can conclude...

Comment: Right, but that should be made more explicit. Also one needs to show that the graph is planar in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

We first prove the necessary condition. Let e be any edge in the unique cycle
in G. Note that deleting e still leaves the graph connected. Now, G −e is a connected
graph with no cycles. Hence, G −e is a tree that has n vertices and n −1 edges. Hence G
has n edges.
We now prove the sufficiency condition. Let G have exactly n edges. If G has no cycles
then since G is connected, it must be a tree and hence must have exactly n−1 edges. Hence,
G must have at least one cycle. Let’s assume that G has more than one cycle. In that case,
let e1 and e2 be two edges such that each belongs to a cycle that does not contain the other.
Hence G−e1 −e2 is connected and has at most n−2 edges. This is a contradiction as any
connected graph with n vertices must have at least n −1 edges. Hence, our assumption
that G has more than one cycle is incorrect. Therefore G must have exactly one cycle.